# How to unzip to the same directory in bash

Tags: macos, bash, unzip

I have hundreds of directories, each containing several zip files. I would like to iterate over each directory and unzip all zip files, placing the contents of the zip files into the same directory as the zip files themselves (without creating new sub-directories). Here's the bash script I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
src="/path/to/directories"
for dir in `ls "$src/"`
do
unzip "$src/$dir/*"
done
```

This script does the unzipping, but it creates thousands of sub-directories and dumps them on my desktop! How can I get the desired behavior? I'm on Mac OSX if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

src=/path/to/directories
for dir in "$src"/*
do
    (cd "$dir" && unzip '*')
done
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I also added the -j parameter so that new sub-directories didn't get created. `(cd "$dir" && unzip -j '*')`